# Make text float: left and picture float:right along with being mobile friendly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Want to add my uni and free Code Camp projects on my website. I'm trying to make text float left and picture float right along with being mobile friendly. For some reason I can only see picture on desktop version but not on mobile. Picture is not displaying on mobile. Only text on the right. At first I've been trying to give text col-xs-2 col-sm-2 and img src="" col-xs-8 col-sm-8 but it didn't work. Now I'm trying to achieve desirable result by making this picture as a background for that section=projects but still doesn't work. How can I include picture on the right? Can't figure out what am I doing wrong? Please help.

Please find pictures attached.

[image: This one that I'm trying to achieve]

[image: This what I get on mobile]
Here is my website: http://www.kiljakandweb.com

```
Here is my **HTML**: 

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </head>
        <body>
     <section id="header" class="text-center">

             <h1>Kiljak<br> + Web </h1>
         <br>
         <br>
         <br>
         <h3> I'm a freelance front-end web developer <br> based in London. I develop responsive, high-performance  <br>websites  using HTML5, CSS, and JavaScript.
         </h3>
         <br>
         <a href="#googleMap"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
     </section>


     <section class="projects">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
        <h2><span style="font-family: 'Open Sans';
        font-size: 200px">01</span> Wikipedia Viewer </h2>
        </div>
        </div>
     </section>

<div id="googleMap">

      <footer>
        <div class="container">
                <div class="text-center">
                      <h4><strong>KILJAK + WEB</strong>
                      </h4>
                        <p>Ace Hotel Shoreditch
                        <br>London, UK E1 6JQ</p>
                          <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li><i class="fa fa-phone fa-fw"></i> (44) 7568599454</li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i> <a href="mailto:edgar.kiljak@kiljakandweb.com">edgar.kiljak@kiljakandweb.com</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <br>
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw fa-3x"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw fa-3x"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr class="small">
                    <p class="text-muted">Copyright &copy; KILJAK + WEB 2016</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        <a id="to-top" href="#top" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up fa-fw fa-1x"></i></a>
    </footer>





      </body>
    </html>
```

And CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300');




#header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top:  50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    background-color: white;


}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
    font-size: 92px;
    line-height: 90px;
    color: black;
}

h2 {
    margin-top:250px;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: normal;;
    color: black;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: lighter !important;
    color: black;
}


hr {

    color: black !important;

}

.fa {
    color: black !important;
}

.fa:hover {
    color: red !important;
}

.projects {
    float: right;
    background-image: url('images/ipad.png');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    margin-top:500px;
    width: 100%; /* Span the entire width of the screen */
    height: 800px;
}

#googleMap {
    padding-top: 100px !important;
    margin-top: -10px;
    width: 100%; /* Span the entire width of the screen */
    height: 400px; /* Set the height to 400 pixels */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%); /* Change the color of the map to black and white */
}

footer {
    position: static;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 100px 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 13px !important;
    font-weight: lighter;
    line-height: 15px;
}

/* Really small phones */
@media screen and (max-width:320px) {}

/* Regular smart phones, including iPhone 6 + with 414px viewport! */
@media screen and (min-width: 321px) {}

/* Regular Tablets from 480 to 800px including Galaxy tablets - 768px is only good for iPad */
@media screen and (min-width: 481px) {}

/* Desktops and Laptops */
@media screen and (min-width: 801px) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a row with 2 columns and put text and picures in seperate columns like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <h2><span style="font-family: 'Open Sans';
        font-size: 200px">01</span> Wikipedia Viewer </h2>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-8">
<img class="img-responsive" src="images/ipad.png">
</div>
</div>
```

You can find a demo code in the below link:
https://jsfiddle.net/Djav/m93p7ove/1/